# Grabbing Recaptcha to process data

Tags: php, curl, captcha

I use the following Code to POST recaptcha details to Verify the valid process.
But still its Not working.

```
$s1 = $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'];
$s2 = $_POST['recaptcha_response_field'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"recaptcha_challenge_field=$s1&recaptcha_response_field=$s2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://domain.com/login.php");

$text = curl_exec($ch);
```

Its still not working
I Made a PHP page in which user need to add the reaptcha details and i am POST it to this Page to verift the Recaptcha But still not working.

help Me.,!
Thankx In Advance.

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get errors?

Comment: Error In the sense always says captcha Incorrect Means when i try it to POST the data the page loads and the captcha also reload as a result shows incorrect. How to make a same session so that that will not reload when i POST that data